# What is the problem with forming 2,3-dimethylcyclohex-2-en-1-one?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

> [image]

I have suggested a mechanism for the formation of 3-ethyl-2-methylcyclohex-2-en-1-one **A**

[image]

but the question says problems would be encountered if a similar route was used to make 2,3-dimethylcyclohex-2-en-1-one **B**. I think perhaps a decarboxylation step is involved? Can someone please explain how to get to **B** and the difficulties in the mechanism?

Comment: It looks like some sort of trick question.  If you count the carbon atoms B has one less but it isn't clear how to remove it under the given conditions.  I think the answer is that B is a typographical error.  Hope this helps.

Comment: A similar route to B sounds to me like just removing one carbon atom from the chain to hope to arrive at B. I actually see no problem with this as long as you are in thermodynamic control … But I could be missing something obvious …

Comment: @jan how can i remove one carbon from the chain?

Comment: As in using a different reactant.

Comment: @Jan oh i see. As in changing the starting material completely? That was not clear from the question.. I will try it! Thanks!

Comment: @Jan i dont see what the problems are in this reaction?

Comment: @justbehappy Dito. That’s why I’m confused, too ;)

Comment: Could it be due to conjugation with the carbonyl so OH- would attack once more to give the enol compound. However, the ethyl group sterically hinders the approach of OH- @Jan

Answer (score 4):

Your starting product for A is symmetrical, but your starting product for B will be asymmetrical - one carbon less on one side.  This is going to mean you may get 2 or more different products; B may not be your major product, and you'll have to separate them afterwards.  I don't believe there's inherently a tricky difficultly in the mechanism for B.

Comment: Actually no. Under thermodynamic control (i.e. given enough time) the product B is inherently more stable than the potential side product and it *will* form. Reasoning: Tetrasubstituted versus trisubstituted double bond.

Comment: @Jan My two cents: you are right, but the question may not necessarily be. I think this is the answer the question wants. If OP can edit and make a note of this piece of information I'd +1.

Comment: Wouldn't the more favoured enolate in the starting material needed to form B (6-oxo-2-octanone, probably not the IUPAC name) actually mean B as a product is not favoured?

Comment: @Beerhunter As I wrote above, under thermodynamic control **B** is more stable than the side product 2-ethylcyclohex-2-en-1-one and will thus be formed preferentially.